# Using Tensorflow's top_k and scatter_nd

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to write an operation in tensorflow that propagates only the top k values of each feature map.

example:

k=1, input size is `[batch_size, x, y, channels]` let's say it's `[1,2,2,3]`

The output should be the same size and if k=1 than each x,y plane will have only one nonzero.

example in numpy:

```
input = [[[[6.4 1.4 1.3] [2.1  6.5  4.8]][[2.3 9.2  2.8][7.9  5.1 0.6]]]]]
```

output should be:

```
[[[[6.4 0. 0.] [0. 6.5 0.]]  [[0. 9.2 0.] [7.9 0. 0.]]]]
```

in order to do this in tensorflow I would like to use nn.top_k followed by scatter_nd.

the problem is that top_k returns the indices of the requested elements very diffrently from how scatter_nd needs it.

top_k returns array of indices`[[[[0],[1]], [[1],[0]]]]` in shape `(1,2,2,1)`

scatter_nd needs it as a list of all coordinates per value like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Does anyone know about a way to convert between them? or even maybe diffrent approch entirly for this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) only returns the top k values in the *last dimension*. So you have to add back all the other dimensions. Easiest with [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where). Code (tested):

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.constant( [ [ [ [6.4, 1.4, 1.3], [2.1,  6.5,  4.8] ], [ [2.3, 9.2, 2.8], [7.9, 5.1, 10.6] ] ] ] )

t, idx = tf.nn.top_k( inp, k = 2 )
idx_one_hot = tf.one_hot( idx, depth = 3 )
idx_red = tf.reduce_sum( idx_one_hot, axis = -2 )
idx2 = tf.where( tf.not_equal( idx_red, 0 ) )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( idx2 ) )
```

Outputs (note I've changed the last number in your example to have an index of 2 as well, only 0s and 1s looked a bit misleading as if it were a boolean tensor):

> [[0 0 0 0]
>    [0 0 0 1]
>    [0 0 1 1]
>    [0 0 1 2]
>    [0 1 0 1]
>    [0 1 0 2]
>    [0 1 1 0]
>    [0 1 1 2]]

Please note, this loses the order of indices in the last dimension as reported by top_k, it changes it to increasing order in the indices themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer peter! however this seems to work only for the case of k=1. is there a way for k>1?

Comment: Ok happy to help. :) Would you accept the answer then? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers